# Typescript non-empty Array return length of size zero

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently having trouble understanding the problem with my following piece of code. Any advices or informations are more than welcome!

```
getProjects(client):string[] {
      client = client.trim();

      var tempProjects = [];
  
      // if(this.m_projects.length >= 1){
      //   this.m_projects = [];
      //   this.m_tasks = [];
      //   this.sTask = null;
      //   this.sProject = null;
      // }
      
      
      const curTaskObservable = this.afs.collection('users').doc('myFirstUser')
      .collection('clients').doc(client).collection('projects')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((data:any)=>{
        data.forEach(el=>{
          if(this.m_projects.indexOf(el.name) === -1){
            this.m_projects.push(el.name);
            tempProjects.push(el.name);
          } 
        });
      });
      
      console.log("array length : " + tempProjects.length);
      console.log(" array content : " + tempProjects);
      return tempProjects;
```

The output, as shown below prints the length "0" and for the array content, the length "1". How can that be possible, and is there a way to get the correct length value. Thank you!

[The output of the console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWrlx.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
subscribe((data:any)=>{
        data.forEach(el=>{
          if(this.m_projects.indexOf(el.name) === -1){
            this.m_projects.push(el.name);
            tempProjects.push(el.name);
          } 
        });
      });
      
      console.log("array length : " + tempProjects.length);
      console.log(" array content : " + tempProjects);
      return tempProjects;
```

It is not that the array is empty. It is that you have not yet understand how asynchronous code get's executed. The block inside the subscription can be executed after the `console.log` which prints the array size.

Move the `console.log` inside the subscription block.

```
 subscribe((data:any)=>{
            data.forEach(el=>{
              if(this.m_projects.indexOf(el.name) === -1){
                this.m_projects.push(el.name);
                tempProjects.push(el.name);
                console.log("array length : " + tempProjects.length);
              } 
            });
          });
```

This would be a good step to understand how asynchronous code works.